# Occasional flicker when transitioning between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, flicker

This is a new issue with my app that occurs both on Lollipop and KitKat.  I can't reproduce it consistently, but [here is a screen capture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_videoeditor&v=yiIEFOpkS0M#t=19) of it happening twice (in about five seconds).  I have recently updated the `support` and `appcompat` libraries.  Also, I have `android:windowAnimationStyle` set to `@null`.

Any idea as to what could be causing this?  Has anyone else witnessed something similar?

**Edit:** I ruled out doing too much work on the UI thread by making two simple `Activities` and switching between them.  [You will notice here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIBmvf-zTqk#t=19) that this issue still occurs randomly.

**Edit:** I tried setting `windowDisablePreview` to `true` as per a suggestion in `#android-dev`, but the issue was still present.  Also, I noticed that the flicker effect occurs more frequently in the emulator.

**Edit:** I think this has to do with there being no animation when transitioning.  If I remove the `android:windowAnimationStyle @null` I don't see the flicker.  I know for sure this never happened before the Lollipop appcompat.

Comment: Too much workload on UI thread?

Comment: Building upon what @ingamedeo said, do you have anything in your `onResume()` that could potentially block the UI thread for enough time to cause the flicker?

Comment: @ingamedeo I'm doing some things that aren't exactly light, but I have been doing those same things for a long time now and have only recently noticed the issue.

Comment: @dcharms See above comment.

Comment: @mattblang Well, it may have appeared recently due to the update to newer Android versions that require more hardware resources on your system. By the way... You should NOT perform intensive CPU operations on the UI thread! Move them to a worker thread ;) Thumbs up appreciated

Comment: Regardless of "well, it works for me", just don't do it.  What about users with less powerful devices?  To you it looks fine, to them it looks ugly.

Comment: @Simon You got exactly my point ;)

Comment: @ingamedeo Well, I didn't mean they were heavy operations either.  The screen that causes the issue in the [video I linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_videoeditor&v=yiIEFOpkS0M#t=19) is getting a handle to `SharedPreferences`, registering with `Otto`, starting a `Loader`, and starting a `Retrofit` request.  I really don't think the issue is with UI workload.  That screen is injecting two different fragments (nav drawer and content), but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Simon See above comment.

Comment: @mattblang I see, I don't know exactly how Otto works and can't really tell you whether they can be considered heavy, my advice is to execute these operations after the activity/fragment transition to exclude any possible relation with UI workload.

Comment: @ingamedeo So I did a test with two simple `Activities` and it still occurs.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIBmvf-zTqk#t=19).

Comment: @Simon So I did a test with two simple `Activities` and it still occurs.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIBmvf-zTqk#t=19).

Comment: @mattblang May I ask you to change the hardware platform you are testing your app on? It seems like to me you are using the Android Emulator, does the same issue happen on a real device?

Comment: @ingamedeo That video is taken on a `Moto X 2014`.  I also reproduced on a `Nexus 4` running `Lollipop` and a `Galaxy Tab 4` running `KitKat`.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` to revert my animations back to the Android default.  This fixed the problem.  I am not accepting this answer because I should be able to disable animations without the flicker effect;  but I want to post this to let any future viewers know.

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue at the moment and it's interesting that you mentioned `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` because I noticed it started to occur only after I added this piece of code to a package. Any further ideas about this issue?